# Moment of ineirtia using Green's theorem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let C be a simple closed curve in the xy-plane and let I denote the moment of inertia of the region enclosed by C.

Show that an integer n exists such that

nI= Line integral of $\int x^3 dy- y^3 dx $  along C in counter-clockwise direction.

I know that moment of inertia can be evaluated by double integral of product of density function and k^2 (k is the perpendicular distance from point in C to z-axis) over the region.

How can I find k^2 ?

Comment: With respect to z-axis?

Comment: yes Moment of inertia about the z-axis

Comment: Hint: Pythagoras.

Comment: What does "perpendicular distance" actually mean?? is it

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the density is unity. Let $R$ be the region enclosed by $C$. By Green's theorem,

$$\int_C (x^3\, dy - y^3\, dx) = \iint_R \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^3) - \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-y^3)\right)\, dx\, dy = \iint_R (3x^2 + 3y^2)\, dx\, dy = 3I.$$

Therefore, $n = 3$.

Comment: The only part I don't understand is that how does the last double integral become 3I?

Comment: Since Moment of inertia in double integral of product of density function and k^2 (k is a perpendicular distance from point in C to Z-axis), last part of integral only seems like that we have to assume density function is 1 or something

Comment: Sure. It's $3\iint_R (x^2 + y^2)\, dx\, dy$, and $\iint_R(x^2 + y^2)\, dx\, dy = I$ since the perpendicular distance from a point $(x,y) $ to the $z$-axis is $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$.

Comment: Oh, there is a difference between moment of inertia of the plate and moment of inertia of the region..

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mine, could you explain more about "perpendicular distance" and how to find out distance from point in C to any line L ?

Comment: Think of it this way. Given a point $(x,y) \in C$, there is a unique line $\ell$ normal to $L$ which passes through $(x,y)$. The distance from the point $(x,y)$ to the point of intersection of $\ell$ and $L$ is the perpendicular distance from $C$ to $L$.

Comment: @user226741, did you understand?